# Is "demo" understood in all languages?

Tags: programming, technology, computing

The word "demo" is widely used in the information technology field as "demonstration" in many languages.
Many applications are distributed in a "demo" form before users purchase them.
I would like to know if it is a universal word that is actually understood in nearly all languages, especially among people that own a mobile device like tablets and smartphones.
(The above mentioned word is one of those english words that are internationally recognized as standard so an expert could know about it)

Comment: You'd have to ask people who speak several languages. This is the English Stack Exchange, not the Every-Language-Except-English Stack Exchange.

Comment: @SomethingDark Language experts know also the international role of the english terms so I think it's not off topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about English. The site for "generic language experts" is [Linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm going to demo my new 4-wheeler in that race.

Comment: I know quite a lot about maths and the SW of the US. And I use English when I'm talking about these subjects.  But it doesn't make questions about these on-topic here. The site rules specify what questions _are_ on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that *demo* means different things to different fields of expertise. In the home remodeling industry, for example, it usually means "demolish". (Apparently, this meaning is also used by gamers when battling online foes.)

According to the excellent [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=demo), the word "demo" was made popular by the music industry, but didn't start out that way. It was a different kind of demonstration...

> Music recording given out for promotional purposes, 1963. The word was
>   used earlier to mean "a public political demonstration" (1936).

And here's an example from [HGTV.com](http://www.hgtv.com/remodel/interior-remodel/diy-demolition) using *demo* to mean "demolition":

> Everybody likes demolition. Or maybe I should say everybody likes the
>   idea of demolition. On the surface, **demo** is blunt-force fun, uses
>   gross motor skills and delivers almost instant gratification. How cool
>   is that!

Comment: I think it means "demonstration" in the computer applications jargon. I need to know if it is so for a foreign audience too, provided that that audience is already accustomed to english words that are standard in this field.

Comment: @P5music, but this is an English usage forum. You'd need to find that information on a different kind of language site. I was just trying to help you understand that *demo* truly is used differently depending on your subject matter.

Comment: Thank you so much. I mean, language experts know also the international role of the english terms so I think it's not off topic here.

Comment: To know the answer to your question, one would have to know "many languages". I believe this site deals with English usage. You would have to create a list of languages, then check each one.